# Is menopause a design or a degradation?

Tags: human-biology, endocrinology, menstrual-cycle

Does menopause appear to be a designed or an accidental phenomenon?

We might say it is "designed" if there is a biological process that triggers it.  Like menarche, where something genetic says, "Time to ramp up these hormones!"  Or perhaps the ovaries say, "Egg count has dropped below a critical level, time to stop the cycle."

We might say it is "accidental" if it is a byproduct of degeneration like all aging processes, and not the consequence of any particular biological mechanism.

Comment: Great question. I’ll try and write up a proper answer later, but it’s widely considered that the menopause is adaption to avoid inter generational conflict in humans.

Comment: @user438383 — "Widely considered". I look forward to the evidence. Meanwhile, I would observe that most animals don't survive beyond reproductive age, and that this has been a recent development in *H.sapiens*.

Comment: A third idea is that menopause exists to keep women from competing with their own offspring. It forces them to rechanneled resources in helping their descendants which is an advantage in species with such helpless but high energy demand offspring with such slow maturation rates. A woman at menopause age is unlikely to raise new offspring to maturity in the wild, so there is a evolutionary advantage to rechanneling effort into existing offspring.

Answer (score 3):

Just-so stories are a folklore that we love to tell, but it's important not to get too carried away with belief in them.  To conclude the *design* or *purpose* of something, or whether it is *accidental*, implies a very deep understanding of all the possible paths of evolution, a God's-eye view if you will, that typically evades us.  Even so, predictable statistical effects do guide the course of evolution, so we'll attempt to explain anyway.

That said, I'll name two very sensible ways to explain how menopause came to be - almost surely not the *only* two.  One is that it is rooted in the social nature of humans, by comparison with cetaceans (especially orcas) which have a similar segment of their population.  If eusocial insects can have *most* females non-reproductive, it seems easy enough to believe that a lesser non-reproductive population is possible.  [Johnstone and Cant, 2010](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2992708/) ask why older rather than younger women assume this role.  They conclude that [philopatry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philopatry) of males, rather than females, accounts for the uniqueness of these two groups.  When females disperse and males remain, an older female is more related to young individuals than a younger female, because her sons remain in the area.  If the females are philopatric, the effect is reversed.  (Note that in *all* human populations, including hunter-gatherers, there is a substantial contribution from postmenopausal women)

The other way I'll mention is simply that arrested oocytes have a shelf life.  [Huber and Fieder, 2018](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6148287/) argue for this by comparing the age of reproductive senescence with lifespan.  [Their curve](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6148287/figure/Fig1/) levels off a little past the point of human menopause, suggesting it is just hard to keep ovaries going very much longer.

Here's where it's important not to get too caught up in the myth.  A sense of "purpose" would make us argue for one explanation or the other -- but the reality of random evolution means that both can be true.  Oocytes could evolve to surpass current limits of reproductive senescence, and existing patterns of philopatry and social behavior could change.  But for now, this combination of young gametes and social assistance from the elderly seems to work.